# How do I simply stop a thread? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am creating a simple GUI with Tkinter, with three buttons so far. My setup is very simple: i have three functions, and I am attaching those three functions to the three buttons. I understand I have to start a thread for each button to avoid freezing the GUI when clicking on the button (and running the attached function). 
I managed getting a thread to start for each button/function, however I don't know how to kill that thread after the function is finished? I thought it would be simpler but I'm struggling with it.

Here is my *PARTIAL* code below (only showing the parts that matter):

```
import threading

def threadButtonOne():
    threading.Thread(target=Send_Data).start()

def threadButtonTwo():
    threading.Thread(target=Process_Data).start()

def threadButtonThree():
    threading.Thread(target=Process_Data2).start()

btn = Button(window, text="Send Data",font=("Century Gothic", 15), command=threadButtonOne)
btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)

btn = Button(window, text="Data Processing - Step 1",font=("Century Gothic", 15), command=threadButtonTwo)
btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)

btn = Button(window, text="Data Processing - Step 2",font=("Century Gothic", 15), command=threadButtonThree)
btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.45, anchor=CENTER)
```

Comment: look at `Thread.join()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to kill a Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread)

Comment: Why do you think you *need* to kill the threads? A thread will finish and clean up once its function is done.

Comment: You should `join` the threads as proposed and you can also create your threads as `daemon`s so that they are "killed" once the main is stopped